How could the default value ('value=') in instantiating a StringVar in TKinter cause issues in the handling of that StringVar as a dict key?
I have a dictionary of dictionaries to set the values of a set of sliders (Scale() objects) for a bank of radio buttons, and want to set the values in the dictionary first, then recall the appropriate values in the requested position key.  Here's how the dictionaries are set:
attributes_list = ['Gap','Power','Eye','AvK','Babip','Speed','Steal','BR','Def']
position_list = ['C','1B','2B','3B','SS','LF','CF','RF','DH']
team_weights = {}
for position in position_list:
    pos_dict = {}
    for attribute in attributes_list:
        pos_dict[attribute] = tk.DoubleVar(value=100)
    team_weights[position] = pos_dict

the instantiation of the sliders needs to have a dictionary to pull the values from, so this needs to be defined after the declaration of the dictionaries:
current_position = tk.StringVar(value="DH")

here is the function called by the radio buttons to set and recall the data:
def update_sliders(position):
    old_position = current_position.get()
    team_weights[old_position]['Babip'].set(babipSlider.get())
    team_weights[old_position]['AvK'].set(avkSlider.get())
    team_weights[old_position]['Power'].set(powerSlider.get())
    ...etc.

    current_position.set(position)
    babipSlider.set(team_weights[position]['Babip'].get())
    avkSlider.set(team_weights[position]['AvK'].get())
    powerSlider.set(team_weights[position]['Power'].get())
    eyeSlider.set(team_weights[position]['Eye'].get())

finally, the instantiation of the radio buttons, and setting the command to call the update_sliders function, with the parameter of the new position:
currentPositionDHRadioButton = tk.Radiobutton(canvas, text="DH", value="DH", state='normal', command=lambda:update_sliders('DH'))
currentPositionDHRadioButton.grid(column=4,row=17)

so, in theory - when a button is pressed, it should save the data in the dictionary associated with the radio button that was previously pressed, then update the onscreen GUI with the data already saved in the dictionary for the new radio button.  This works - for every radio button, but the one for which the original 'current_position = tk.StringVar(value="")' declaration lists as the default value.  For this radio button, the sliders stay at the position that they were in previously.  The previous values are saved correctly in the dictionary, but the recall does not work - only for whichever button is set as the default position.
So it seems that the dictionary declaration process should be working, that the updating sliders call is working, but there's something about declaring the default value that is causing the problem.  I've checked the TKinter docs, but can't find anything concrete that would be the cause.  Any ideas??
I've tried replacing the initial declaration with different values, calling a select() function on the radio button set as default (or other radio buttons), but they all lead to the same error: the values for whichever is set as default are not recalled.

Similarly, is all the code starting from current_position.set(position) supposed to be inside def update_sliders(position):?

Can't you just use the variable option to RadioButton() so all the buttons will be associated with the same StringVar, which contains the value of the selected radio button?

Indeed - although I'll probably refactor those later lines at some point into another recall_sliders() function, so that's less of a catastrophic omission on my part!!

The short answer is that using the normal variable option won't work in this implementation, because the 'previous' value of the variable needs to be used to set new values in the dictionary before changing the value of StringVar and recalling the settings associated with the new value.
It's a pretty hacky implementation, but bypassing the normal RadioButton() functionality in this way has worked for every other value of StringVar than the default!

For posterity - a slight workaround (a hack of a hacky implementation?) gave better results.  I believe the primary issue was that the definition of the slider variable was as a reference to the default position, which meant that altering the variable directly in the update_sliders() would in fact always be temporarily altering the values of the dictionary with the key of the default position - leading to unpredictable results.
A solution was to define the variable= value for the sliders with 'temp' values that would then be set directly in update_sliders(), so that the slider's state value would be discrete from the stored values for each position.  Also, implementing a 'python native' string variable to store the previous position until it would then be updated at the end of update_sliders() allowed for normal implementation of the variable= parameter of the RadioButtons.
Thanks, all!!
